# Adding Inline Text Component After Ellipsis (Read More Button)

Tags: react-native, styled-components

```
            <Text
              style={{ fontSize: 18, margin: 5 }}
              numberOfLines={message.length > characterLimit ? 3 : 0}
            >
              <Text>{message}</Text>
            </Text>
            <Touchable>
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: AppColors.tealC,
                }}
              >
                Read More
              </Text>
            </Touchable>
          </View>
```

[image]

The problem is in the image above. I want Read More to show up on the same line as the "..."

I have tried many solutions. The main one you may be thinking of is to put the "show more" Text component inside of the "message" Text component, however it is cut off by the ellipsis when I do this thanks to numberOfLines.I have also tried `flexWrap: 'wrap'` and `flexDirection: 'row'` Any fixes to this bizarre issue would be greatly appreciated. I see some fixes in other threads for a similar issue, but they are for web apps and don't have work arounds for "numberOfLines".

Answer (score 3):

We can use a little trick in order to have a `Read more` button nested inside the text component if the text is truncated and set it outside the text component if the text is not truncated. This allows us to keep the button visually next to the last line of text.

We can achieve this with using a state in order to indicate if the text is truncated or not. Consider the following minimal example.

```js
const [isTruncated, setIsTruncated] = useState(true)

const ReadMore = () => {
    return (
      <Text onPress={() => setIsTruncated(!isTruncated)} style={{ color: "green" }}>
        {isTruncated ? "Read more" : " Read less"}
      </Text>
    )
}

<View style={{ padding: 20, flexDirection: "row" }}>
    <Text numberOfLines={isTruncated ? 1 : Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              This is a very very very very very very very very very very long text
       {!isTruncated && <ReadMore />}
    </Text>
    {isTruncated && <ReadMore />}
</View>
```

Here is the initial state of the view.

[image]

Here is the view after pressing `Read more`.

[image]

Comment: This didn't solve my issue... Same problem still nothing changed :/
Except with your solution the read more button shows up even when the text hasn't gone past the number of lines...
The problem isn't getting the read more to show up, it's getting it to be INLINE with the truncated text

Comment: Have you used my solution in an isolated environment? It works on my device as you can see in the provided screenshots

Comment: Yes, it works if you limit the number of lines to 1, but have you tried 2? It won't agree with the word wrap. I can place the read more button at the end of the truncated text...But it will show up outside the chat bubble instead of inside :/

Comment: @DustinB did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue I got a solution for that.

Here is a Package that you can integrate [SeeMoreLibrary](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fawazahmed/react-native-read-more)

It Resolved you solution. Here is the code that I integrated on my app.

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './styles';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import Fonts from '../../utils/Fonts';
import ReadMore from '@fawazahmed/react-native-read-more';

const SeeMore = ({label, text, style, numberOfLines, seeMoreStyle, customStyle}) => {
  const capitalizeFirst = str => {
    return str?.charAt(0)?.toUpperCase() + str?.slice(1);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.root}>
      <ReadMore
        numberOfLines={numberOfLines ? numberOfLines : 2}
        style={
          style
            ? [style, styles.extrafont]
            : customStyle
            ? customStyle
            : [Fonts.style.default, styles.extrafont]
        }
        seeMoreStyle={seeMoreStyle ? seeMoreStyle : styles.btn}
        seeLessStyle={seeMoreStyle ? seeMoreStyle : styles.btn}
        seeLessText={'less'}
        seeMoreText={'more'}>
       {capitalizeFirst(label)}
      </ReadMore>
    </View>
  );
};
export default SeeMore;
```

For more information you can visit [Package Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fawazahmed/react-native-read-more)

[image]